# How can I compare two lists and find the differences between them?

Tags: string, list, coldfusion, refactoring

The following function compares a new list of items to an old one and finds the differences:

1. Items that have been deleted from the old list
2. Items that were added to the new list (not present in the original list).

I wrote two loops to achieve this, and they produced the following output:

> oldItems = "an, old, list" ---> Items To Delete: 'an,old'
>
> newItems = "a, new, list" ---> Items To Create: 'new'

The first issue is `a` should show up in the items to create, but I believe because it's a substring of `an` it's not getting picked up.

The second issue(?) is I doing two loops seems inefficient. Can the code be refactored?

```
public function testList() hint="Compares two lists to find the differences."
{
    local.oldItems = "a, new, list";
    local.newItems = "an, old, list";
    local.toDelete = "";
    local.toCreate = "";

    // Loop over newItems to find items that do not exist in oldItems 
    for (local.i = 1; local.i LTE ListLen(local.newItems, ", "); local.i++)
    {
        if (! ListContains(local.oldItems, ListGetAt(local.newItems, local.i, ", ")))
        {
            local.toCreate = ListAppend(local.toCreate, ListGetAt(local.newItems, local.i, ", "));
        }
    }

    // Loop over old items to find items that do not exist in newItems
    for (local.i = 1; local.i LTE ListLen(local.oldItems, ", "); local.i++)
    {
        if (! ListContains(local.newItems, ListGetAt(local.oldItems, local.i, ", ")))
        {
            local.toDelete = ListAppend(local.toDelete, ListGetAt(local.oldItems, local.i, ", "));
        }
    }

    writeDump(var="Items To Delete: '" & local.toDelete & "'");
    writeDump(var="Items To Create: '" & local.toCreate & "'", abort=true);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I believe you can refactor your code.

I prefer to use the array functions as it does an exact match (including case). This method ensures that "a" is picked up as a difference between the lists.

Hope this helps:

```
<cfscript>
    oldList = "an, old, list";
    newList = "a, new, list";

    result = compareLists(oldList, newList);

    writeDump(result);

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public struct function compareLists (
        required string listA,
        required string listB
    ){

        local.a = listToArray(arguments.listA, ',');
        local.b = listToArray(arguments.listB, ',');

        local.itemsNotInListB = [];
        local.itemsNewInListB = [];

        // Compare all items in 'list A' to 'list B'
        for (local.item in local.a) {
            if (!arrayContains(local.b, local.item))
            {
                arrayAppend(local.itemsNotInListB, local.item);
            }
        }
        // Compare all items in 'list B' to 'list A'
        for (local.item in local.b) {
            if (!arrayContains(local.a, local.item))
            {
                arrayAppend(local.itemsNewInListB, local.item);
            }
        }

        return {
             newItems = local.itemsNewInListB
            ,deletedItems = local.itemsNotInListB
        };
    }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Aaron, this is awesome, thank you. I think it will be very useful for me in general. For my purposes, however, I think I will use one loop and use a ListFind() function as Ray mentioned. I think your UDF is awesome, but it's a bit of an overkill in this situation. Thanks for the demo!

Comment: No worries. But, I did answer your question :)

Comment: just revisiting this.. running this code gives an error: You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class coldfusion.runtime.Array as a structure - it appears that for in loops don't work on arrays :-?

Answer (score 3):

The answer to getting the correct matches is to use the `ListFind()` function with a delimiter instead of `ListContains()`:

```
if (! ListFind(local.oldItems, ListGetAt(local.newItems, local.i, ", "), ", ")) {}
```

The delimiter is necessary otherwise the function will try and match the whole string.

No answer for the refactoring, though.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 list UDFs on cflib.org:

List Compare - http://cflib.org/udf/listCompare - Compares one list against another to find the elements in the first list that don't exist in the second list. Performs the same funciton as the custom tag of the same name.

List Diff - http://cflib.org/udf/ListDiff - Compares two lists and returns the elements that do not appear in both lists.

List Diff Dup - http://cflib.org/udf/ListDiffDup - This function compares two lists and will return a new list containing the difference between the two input lists. This function is different from ListDiff as it treats duplicate elements within the lists as distinct elements.

Answer (score 3):

Seriously, don't reinvent the wheel. Use Java Lists or Sets, ColdFusion runs atop a JVM:

```
<cfscript>
oldItems = "an, old, list"; //Items To Delete: 'an,old'
newItems = "a, new, list"; //Items To Create: 'a,new'
// ArrayList could be HashSet if items in both lists are expected to be unique
oldItems = createObject("java", "java.util.ArrayList").init(listToArray(oldItems, ", "));
newItems = createObject("java", "java.util.ArrayList").init(listToArray(newItems, ", "));

itemsToDelete = createObject("java", "java.util.HashSet").init(oldItems);
itemsToDelete.removeAll(newItems);

itemsToCreate = createObject("java", "java.util.HashSet").init(newItems);
itemsToCreate.removeAll(oldItems);
</cfscript>

<cfoutput>
itemsToDelete: #listSort(arrayToList(itemsToDelete.toArray()),"textNoCase")#<br /><!--- an,old --->
itemsToCreate: #listSort(arrayToList(itemsToCreate.toArray()),"textNoCase")#<!--- a,new --->
</cfoutput>
```

As a bonus [here's a link to Java code I drew my example from](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Setoperationsunionintersectiondifferencesymmetricdifferenceissubsetissuperset.htm).

Comment: I really have to come to terms with using Java and Coldfusion together. Since I know little about Java the prospect of having to use it puts off a little; yet it seems so simple and loaded with functionality.

Comment: Bruce Eckel's **Thinking in Java** http://www.amazon.com/Thinking-Java-4th-Bruce-Eckel/dp/0131872486 is a great book for learning the language. The best ColdFusion -> Java book I'm aware of is **Java for ColdFusion Developers** http://www.amazon.com/Java-ColdFusion-Developers-Eben-Hewitt/dp/0130461806

Answer (score 2):

Did you try searching CFLib.org? There are multiple list functions including one to find differences. As for your issues with substrings, read the documentation on ListContains. This is how it is supposed to work. Try ListFind or ListFindNoCase instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
<cfset strListTupla = "SKU,CANTIDAD,VENTA">
<cfset strListSend = "CANTIDAD,SKU">

<cfset strListSend = ListSort(strListSend, "textnocase", "asc")>
<cfset strListTupla = ListSort(strListTupla, "textnocase", "asc")>

<cfset strListTupla = ListToArray (strListTupla)>
<cfloop index="j" from="1" to="#Arraylen(strListTupla)#">
    <cfoutput>
    <cfif NOT ListFind(strListSend, strListTupla[j])>
        Not Found #strListTupla[j]#
    </cfif><br/>
    </cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

With that I can search for the item to see if it is in the list or not and likewise show that element is missing.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 loops practically does the same thing, the only difference is that the lists have swapped place. Totally unneccessary. You only need to check one way; Old -> New. NOT the otherway around too (Old <- New).

Create an instance of the 2 lists and send them through one loop where you check if the old list contains an item equal to any of the new items.

I don't know how good a for-loop is for this purpose as local.i in old list can be index[7] and the exact same item you need to check on in the new can be index[3] after possible changes.

Comment: ziga, the thing is, I need to identify the items that were added (to create them), and the items that were removed, to delete them... I can't think of a way to do this without using the two loops...